Does the spectrum of the stalk of a point of a noetherian scheme contain an open subscheme about that point?
I am just proving the local consistency of Hilbert polynomials on flat families. All the proofs I have found till now, they use a map $ i_{y}: \operatorname{Spec}(\mathscr O_{Y,y})\rightarrow Y$ and consider $Y$ as a local noetherian ring and proves the consistency.
My question is that, how can they say it is locally constant, is there any open set contained in the $\operatorname{Spec}(\mathscr O_{Y,y})$?
Here $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a flat projective morphism where $Y$ is locally noetherian.
It is a trivial question I know, but I am stuck, please bear with me. Thank you.

No, this does not in general contain an open neighborhood of the point: consider $Y=\Bbb A^1_k$ and $y$ the origin. Then $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}\cong k[t]_{(t)}$, the spectrum of a DVR. This contains two points, one closed and one generic point; if this contained an open neighborhood of $y$ in $Y$, the closed points would be dense, but they are not.
Instead what you can use here is that $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$ contains all of the generalizations of $y$. We say $y_1$ is a generalization of $y_0$ if $y_0\in \overline{\{y_1\}}$. If we know that a function from a sober noetherian topological space (i.e. a noetherian scheme) $Y$ has the same value on $y_0$ and $y_1$ for any generalization $y_1$ of $y_0$, then we can prove this function is locally constant: decomposing $Y$ as a union of irreducible components $Y_1\cup\cdots\cup Y_n$, any two points $z,z'\in Y_i$ both have common generalization the generic point of $Y_i$, so the values of the function must be constant on each irreducible component. If $Y_i\cap Y_j\neq\emptyset$, then there is a point in the intersection which has common generalizations the generic points of $Y_i$ and $Y_j$, which then forces the function to have the same value on $Y_i$ and $Y_j$. Repeating, we find that on every connected component, the function has the same value since a connected component of a noetherian topological space is the union of finitely many irreducible components.
To generalize to the locally noetherian case, first restrict to an open neighborhood of our point which is noetherian, then run the above proof. This will give the function is locally constant.

Thank you for your valuable time in answering my question, but can you please clarify why the function is constant on an irreducible component? I know irreducible components are connected, so it is enough to show locally constant. Also, any point $z$ has a unique generalisation point $z'$ (in that irreducible component), but I can not see why they have the same value. Thank you in advance.

Oh, I think I got it. All the generalisations are contained in $Spec \mathscr O_{Y,z}$ including z too. There it is constant. IS it true? Thank you so much!

@AnubhabPahari it's not that every point has a unique generalization point, but rather that every point which lies in an irreducible component generalizes to the generic point of that irreducible component. Since $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}{Y,y}$ contains all the generalizations of $y$, if the function is constant on $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}{Y,y}$, the answer proves that the function will be constant in a neighborhood of $y$.

Nice, now it is clear! Thank you so much for your time and attention!
